# Android Adapter not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have followed [this](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-custom-listview-example/) tutorial for the creation of a custom adapter.This link is mentioned in the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view) SO question.

The codes are given as follows:

MyMainView.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.context.GlobalSearch">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/globalSearch_editBrandData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:hint="Enter Name"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/globalSearch_listResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/globalSearch_editBrandData"
    android:visibility="visible"
>
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/globalSearch_errorMessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/globalSearch_editBrandData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Please enter the correct data"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

In the list for for each element I want to display an Image and some text. So my edited `listview` fields are defined as:

MyEdited.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:elevation="1dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/globalSearch_imageView"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/globalSearch_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/globalSearch_imageView"
        android:text = "Puma"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the adapter for the list view is defined as:

GlobalSearchInformation.java

```
import android.util.Log;

public class GlobalSearchInformation {

private int drawableID;
private String textDetails;

public GlobalSearchInformation(int drawbaleID, String textDetails)
{
    super();
    this.drawableID = drawableID;
    this.textDetails = textDetails;
}

public void setTextDetails(String textDetails)
{
    this.textDetails = textDetails;
}

public String getTextDetails()
{
    return textDetails;
}

public void setDrawableID(int drawableID)
{
    this.drawableID = drawableID;
}

public int getDrawableID()
{
    return drawableID;
}
```

}

GlobalSearchAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class GlobalSearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
protected List<GlobalSearchInformation> globalSearchList;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public GlobalSearchAdapter(Context context, List<GlobalSearchInformation> globalSearchList)
{
    this.globalSearchList = globalSearchList;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return globalSearchList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return globalSearchList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return globalSearchList.get(position).getDrawableID();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.globalsearch_listview, parent, false);
        holder.globalsearchadapter_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.globalSearch_textView);
        holder.globalsearchadapter_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.globalSearch_imageView);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    GlobalSearchInformation gsi = globalSearchList.get(position);
    holder.globalsearchadapter_image.setImageResource(gsi.getDrawableID());
    holder.globalsearchadapter_text.setText(gsi.getTextDetails());
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView globalsearchadapter_image;
    TextView globalsearchadapter_text;
}
}
```

GlobalSearch.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import APP.infrastructure.models.Merchant;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class GlobalSearch extends ActionBarActivity {



ListView listViewGlobal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_global_search);

    final AutoCompleteTextView actSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.globalSearch_editBrandSearch);
    final ListView lvSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.globalSearch_listResult);
    final TextView tvSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.globalSearch_errorMessage);

    List<Merchant> merchants = Merchant.findWithQuery(Merchant.class,"select * from MERCHANT");
    ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<merchants.size(); i++)
    {
        al.add(i, merchants.get(i).getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, al);
    actSearch.setAdapter(adapter);

    actSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                String mEdit = actSearch.getText().toString();
                List<Merchant> merchants = Merchant.findWithQuery(Merchant.class,"select * from MERCHANT where UPPER(NAME) LIKE \'"+mEdit.toUpperCase()+"%\'");

                if(merchants.size()==0)
                {
                    Log.d("debug", "Alert dialog: does not exist");
                    lvSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tvSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    ArrayList <GlobalSearchInformation> arrayInformation = new ArrayList<GlobalSearchInformation>();
                    Log.d("global search", "merchant size != 0");
                    GlobalSearchInformation globalSearch_Page = new GlobalSearchInformation(R.drawable.image_id, merchants.get(0).getName());
                    GlobalSearchInformation globalSearch_Feed = new GlobalSearchInformation(R.drawable.image_id, "Posts by "+merchants.get(0).getName());
                    GlobalSearchInformation globalSearch_Store = new GlobalSearchInformation(R.drawable.image_id, merchants.get(0).getName()+" stores around you");
                    GlobalSearchInformation globalSearch_Alerts = new GlobalSearchInformation(R.drawable.image_id, merchants.get(0).getName()+" Events");
                    arrayInformation.add(globalSearch_Page);
                    arrayInformation.add(globalSearch_Feed);
                    arrayInformation.add(globalSearch_Store);
                    arrayInformation.add(globalSearch_Alerts);
                    GlobalSearchAdapter adapter = new GlobalSearchAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayInformation);
                    lvSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_global_search, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

All this is being compiled and is running without an error but on viewing the `listview` after entering the data in the `autocomplete textview`, the elements from the database are being retrieved but the `listview` remains empty. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Check weather getview is called ? if so  then check the data assignment

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki the getView method is being called. How do I check for data assignment?

Comment: see this is what exactly u want..http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use application context to inflate the list view. Use activity context instead.

  GlobalSearchAdapter adapter = new GlobalSearchAdapter(GlobalSearch.this, arrayInformation);
  lvSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
- Don't initilize the adpater each time `onEditorAction` fuction is called, instead just update the data in adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
- `globalSearch_textView` is overlapping the `ListView` so list view won't be visible. Change the height of text view to wrap content.

  ```
     <TextView

      android:id="@+id/globalSearch_textView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/globalSearch_imageView"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Puma" />
  ```

Comment: Now I am getting the text but not the image. Any reason why this is not working? Also, what's the difference between the two contexts and when to use them?

Comment: Did the change as you asked. The image is still not visible.

Comment: Normally activity context is used to inflate the views. http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/ - this article has nice explanation about difference between different context.

Comment: And the image problem??

Comment: Can you try chnaging the height and width of `globalSearch_textView` to `wrap_content`?